# What would be a good hash function(or something similar) for an unique integer array?

Tags: algorithm, math, go

I'm writing a simple program to analyse the lottery. I'm curious about how often the same number patterns appear.

Here's my working code in Golang:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math/rand"
    "os"
    "sort"
    "sync"

    "github.com/mitchellh/hashstructure"
)

func do(n int, ch chan bool) {
    hashes := make(map[uint64]struct{})

    for i := 0; i < n; i++ {
        numbers := rand.Perm(45)[:6]
        sort.Ints(numbers)

        hash, err := hashstructure.Hash(numbers, nil)
        if err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }

        if _, ok := hashes[hash]; ok {
            ch <- true
            break
        } else {
            hashes[hash] = struct{}{}
        }
    }
}

func main() {
    n := 1000

    ch := make(chan bool)
    duplicated := 0.0
    done := make(chan struct{})

    wg := sync.WaitGroup{}
    for i := 0; i < n; i++ {
        wg.Add(1)
        go func() {
            defer wg.Done()
            do(800, ch)
        }()
    }

    go func() {
        wg.Wait()
        close(done)
    }()

    for {
        select {
        case <-ch:
            duplicated += 1
        case <-done:
            fmt.Printf("duplicated ratio: %.2f%%\n", duplicated/float64(n)*100)
            os.Exit(0)
        }
    }
}
```

I'm currently using https://github.com/mitchellh/hashstructure for hashing integer array(in Golang, type of `[]int`). I'm looking for a much efficient way to test if the lottery numbers were duplicated, since the library's function is considered as slow due to the reflections.

I first thought something like this:

```
func hashFunc(v []int) int {
    hash := 1
    for _, x := range v {
        hash ^= x
    }
    return hash
}
```

But it generated hash collision. Could you suggest me a better way to hash int arrays(elements are unique, and in range 1~45) or even another approach to efficiently test if there were duplicated int array in past? Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can skip hashing and just treat it as one 64-bit number. Each lottery number is smaller than 256 and can be contained in 1 byte. You have 6 numbers, so that's 6 bytes and can be contained in 64-bit which is 8 bytes.

https://play.golang.org/p/JHLfHIhAUdd

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func hashFunc(v []uint8) uint64 {
    var hash uint64
    var i uint
    for _, x := range v {
        hash |= uint64(x) << (i * 8)
        i++
    }
    return hash
}

func main() {
    fmt.Printf("hashFunc ({1,2,3,4,5,6}) = %#x", hashFunc([]uint8{1,2,3,4,5,6}))
}
```

Comment: Wow, I never thought this solution. Thank you

Comment: the range is only 1-45 so a number can be stored in 6 bits and the 6-tuple would need only 36 bits

Comment: ... and with a suitably clever encoding, since there are "only" about 8.15 million different combinations, 23 bits should be enough.